# Save docker images in mounted Volume

Tags: ubuntu, docker, mount

I've a small HD (24GB) on `/dev/sda` and another bigger under `/dev/sdb`.

I would like to teach docker to save images in the second HD. I tried with the `-g` flag in `/etc/default/docker` file, but this will create a folder before the HD is mounted.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

I'm running on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1. Mount `/dev/sda` into `/var/lib/docker` using the `_netdev` flag in `/etc/fstab`
2. Start you daemon with `-g /var/lib/docker`